# Onclick event for horizontal list item which is present in another listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have an listView with TextView and another horizontal listView corresponding to that listView. now i need to write onclick event for list item in the horizontal listview.i can't get the parent list item position(vertical listview position).please help me. Thanks in advance.
   // First Listview for Vertical

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"  /> 
</RelativeLayout>

  //Adapter Getview for first list
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{   
    LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);  
    title.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getSite());    
    typeId = mArrayList.get(position).getTypeId();   
    hori_view = (TwoWayView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hor_list); 
    mChildList = mArrayList.get(position).getChildArrList(); 
    HorizontalAdapter horListAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(mContext, R.layout.hori_list,mChildList);
    hori_view.setAdapter(horListAdapter);
    horListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    hori_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {    
            mChildList =  mArrayList.get(position).getChildArrList();                   // Here i need parent list position 
            String text = mChildList.get(position).getChannel().toString();
            int cId = mChildList.get(position).getChannelId(); 
            int pen = mChildList.get(position).getPending(); 
            int typeId = mChildList.get(position).getSiteid(); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,ChannelDetails.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            Bundle bundle = new  Bundle();
            bundle.putString("channel", text);
            bundle.putInt("typeId", typeId);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

// Second list for horizontal view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Title" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/> 

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
              android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView 
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 android:id="@+id/hor_list"
                 style="@style/TwoWayView"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                 tools:context=".MainActivity" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

// second adapter for second list(Horizontal list)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View retval = null;
        if(retval == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            retval = mInflater.inflate(this.resource, null);
            holder = new Holder();
        }
        holder.image = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.pending = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.textOne); 
        holder.channel = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.text1); 
        holder.chan_id = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.text2); 
        holder.text3 = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.text3); 
        mChannel = mChildList.get(position).getChannel(); 
        holder.channel.setText(mChannel);
        holder.pending.setText(String.valueOf(mChildList.get(position).getPending()));
        holder.chan_id.setText(String.valueOf(mChildList.get(position).getChannelId())); 
        if(mChildList.get(position).getSiteid() == 100)
        { 
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb_icon1);
            holder.text3.setText("facebook");
        }
        else if(mChildList.get(position).getSiteid() == 200)
        { 
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tr_icon1);
            holder.text3.setText("twitter");
        }
        else if(mChildList.get(position).getSiteid() == 300)
        { 
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_icon1);
            holder.text3.setText("linkedin");
        }
        retval.setTag(holder);
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post some code, to show what you have tried and also some error logs

Comment: Please check the code above which have edited... thanks in advance

Comment: store the position in a temporary variable and access it in the onitem click